# How to parse data from Gridview row to another page using C# and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I would like to parse a row of data from `Gridview` in ASP.NET to a second page displaying contents of the row data from the previous page. My `Gridview` has already been linked to the database.

My current `Gridview` looks something like this:

[image]

I would like to achieve this when I click on the send details hyperlink:

[image]

If I click on the second row the data from that row will display in the next page

The following codes are what I had put under my link button itemTemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="viewTours" runat="server" CommandName="view" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("name") %>' PostBackUrl='<%#"~/details.aspx?RowIndex=" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'>View</asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

This is my page load method from the second page where I want to load the data from.

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        int rowIndex = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["RowIndex"]);
        GridView GridView = (GridView)this.Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("GridView");
        GridViewRow row = GridView.Rows[rowIndex];
        name.Text = (row.FindControl("name") as Label).Text;
        //name.Text = row.Cells[0].Text; (this did not work either, i got the same error)
    }
}
```

However I get a squiggly line on name.Text saying that it does not exist, even though I do have a label with the id name in the design view of my html (second) page.

How can I make it such that I can parse data from the selected Gridview row to another page? Assuming that I can customize the second page and put the labels wherever I like.

This is the code from my gridview. As my binding has been done through the UI I dont have much codes for it, except to redirect the selected gridview row to another page.

```
    protected void GridView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["tour"] = GridView;
    Response.Redirect("tourDetails.aspx");


}
```

I still get the error that the label text does not exist, when it actually exists in the page itself.

[image]

Image of the Label with the id=name:

[image]

My label DOES contain runat="server":
[image]

Comment: You are getting this error because `row.FindControl("name")` is null. Are you sure you are using the correct name? `FindControl` Searches specified id parameter. Here your label id is "Label1".

Comment: my Label ID here is from my first page with the grid view, I'm trying to load the selected gridview row data to my second page, which already has a label id "name"

Comment: From the many way of [passing values between Web Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx), you choose the uncool one, imo.

Comment: May we have the code of the Grid please?

Comment: I've visited that web page before, it only shows how to parse static data, not data from gridview (shows database data). I tried that, did not work either

Comment: @DragandDrop I have edited my question, please take a look

Comment: @derloopkat I have edited my question to prove to you that it has runat="server"

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing binding data with structure. When you try to get a control with the `name` key, you really mean `Label1`, so change

```
name.Text = (row.FindControl("name") as Label).Text;
```

to

```
name.Text = (row.FindControl("Label1") as Label).Text;
```

Comment: Both are the same, I don't see any changes

Comment: I have changed name to Label1, it didn't work either, I still get the error that the name Label does not exist (id=name)

Comment: and where exactly is the label with id="name" ? I mean, your code says name.Text, for this to compile there should be a name object somewhere

Comment: @depressedGirl yes, unfortunately I missed changing name to Label1. Please, check my edit.

Comment: @DragandDrop LOL, yes, indeed!

Comment: And it could be something else as op claim to have a control with id=name..

Comment: @DragandDrop yes, I agree. I will await for further specifications here so I can improve my answer.

Comment: @derloopkat I have edited my question to show you the existence of that label

Comment: @depressedGirl are you sure the Label is already generated when you try to find it? Can you show us some code related to that label?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes, it has already been generated, it is in my design view of my page. There's no codes to that label except the one I uploaded in my question