# One column GridView data to multiple chart series

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create a chart having multiple series from same gridview column.

My GridView data (from Stored Procedure):

```
Name  |  Month   |  Volume
A     |  2019-01 |  1400
B     |  2019-01 |  1100
B     |  2019-02 |   400
C     |  2019-01 |  6500
B     |  2019-03 |  6500
A     |  2019-02 |   500
C     |  2019-02 |    35
```

And I would like to add a Chart with Volume/Name on the axes and seperate series for each month like one serie for 2019-01, another for 2019-02.

For the example above I'll have three series.

I'm very new to ASP.NET and I'll be glad for any clue how I can achive that. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You first have to group the data by months.  I did that in code below by creating a pivot table and grouping the data by Names.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication106
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Month", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Volume", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"A", DateTime.ParseExact("2019-01", "yyyy-MM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 1400});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", DateTime.ParseExact("2019-01", "yyyy-MM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 1100 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", DateTime.ParseExact("2019-02", "yyyy-MM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 400 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "C", DateTime.ParseExact("2019-01", "yyyy-MM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 6500 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "B", DateTime.ParseExact("2019-03", "yyyy-MM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 6500 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A", DateTime.ParseExact("2019-02", "yyyy-MM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 500 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "C", DateTime.ParseExact("2019-02", "yyyy-MM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 35 });

            DateTime[] dates = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Month")).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            foreach (DateTime date in dates)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(date.ToString("yyyy-MM"), typeof(int));
            }


            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Name")).ToList();

            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                DataRow newRow = pivot.Rows.Add();
                newRow["Name"] = group.Key;
                foreach(DataRow row in group)
                {
                    newRow[row.Field<DateTime>("Month").ToString("yyyy-MM")] = row.Field<int>("Volume");
                }

            }


        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks jdweng! It is very clear. 
Actually the data is in GridView. How can I collect GridView data to dt?

Comment: You do not need to use a datatable.  You can group output to any type object.  See following posting on method to read gridview in asp.net : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887018/how-to-parse-data-from-gridview-row-to-another-page-using-c-sharp-and-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: Thanks a lot @jdwend!